# for loop over a list of files to append relevant file name to all respective colnames per file

Tags: r, for-loop, filenames, names

I am looking to append the file name to all respective column names in each data frame specified in a list.

The list is made using:

```
filegroup <- as.list(dir(pattern="*ForwardTransitionResults.txt"))
```

I then made a "for loop" to append the file name to each column name for each file in the list using:

```
for (i in filegroup){

  d <- basename(i)

  colnames(i) <- paste(d, colnames(i), sep = "_")

}
```

But I keep getting:

Error in,

```
colnames<-(*tmp*, value = "20161014_Milk_SWATH_48min_1.wiff.qresult_ForwardTransitionResults.txt_")
```

attempt to set `colnames` on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: You haven't read the file.  Probably you need `d1 <- read.table(d, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); colnames(d1) <- paste(d, colnames(d1), sep="_")` or so.

Comment: Thanks akrun - I added an "assign" to keep the object name the same as the file name.

for (i in filegroup){
  d  <- basename(i)
  d1 <- read.table(i, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings = "NA", sep = "\t"); 
  colnames(d1) <- paste(d, colnames(d1), sep="_")
  assign(i, d1)
}